# how can i remove TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff) from the TSL 1.0 Cipher Suites List

Tags: android, ssl

i want to remove TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV  from the TSL 1.0 Cipher Suites List with code like :

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory
{
 //..... 
@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose)
    throws IOException
{
    SSLSocket mySocket = (SSLSocket)sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);

    String oriCiphers[] = sock.getEnabledCipherSuites();

    List<String> myCiphersList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String string : oriCiphers)
    {
        if (!string.contains("TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV"))
        {
            myCiphersList .add(string);
        }
    }       
    sock.setEnabledCipherSuites(myCiphersList.toArray(new String[myCiphersList.size()]));
    return mySocket;
}

///
}
```

but it doesn't work~ 
how can i remove TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff) from the TSL 1.0 Cipher Suites List.Thanks!

Comment: This is not a real cipher. Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: i know it is not a real cipher,but there are security risks in some conditions,so i want to romove it from cipher suites list.now i have no idea how to do .

Comment: Since this pseudo cipher is actually used to solve security problems I wonder what kind of security issues this should be which were introduced with this cipher.